# How to calculate angle length in rectangle?

Tags: geometry

I have a rectangle of height 8cm and width 16cm. I want to draw lines in diffrent angles from center left of rectangle. I know the height, width and angle. With these values. Is it possible to calculate the length of angle line that is a, b, c, d and e.?

I have drawn a rough diagram as in screenshot. If you have any idea please share a formula. Or code in javascript would be great!

[image]

Comment: You can use trigonometry. $a = 4/ \cos(30)$ for example.

Comment: Notice that because the face at which the line terminates on the right changes at certain angles (in this case $\frac{\pi}{2} \pm \arctan \frac{1}{4} \approx 1.571 \pm 0.245\,\textrm{rad} \approx 90^\circ \pm 14.0^\circ$), the formula will change at those angles, i.e., it will be natural to represent the function with a piecewise function.

Comment: Thank you @TravisWillse, can you please write the formula here for all angles?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. As mentioned in the comments, you'll have to use trigonometry to calculate the lengths $a,b,c,d,e$ $$a=e=\frac{4}{\cos30^\circ}$$$$b=d=\frac{4}{\cos60^\circ}$$ $$c=16$$

Comment: @Vasili,  Will this work for the angle which is greater than diagonal angle.? If the angle is greater than diagonal angle. Angle line will touch the right edge of rectangle. So, Line length may depend on width of rectangle as well??

Comment: @narayannyaupane not entirely...as Travis has pointed out...the formula will change

Comment: @narayannyaupane: I posted javascript code, check it out. The formula will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the left, using trig, cos(30º)=4/a, which gives us a=(8√3)/3.
Similarly, we use sin(30º)=4/b (b=8).
Since they have the same angles, d=b and e=a.
Trivially, c=16cm, as it is the length of the rectangle.

Comment: How is sin60=4/b

Comment: Yeah I got mixed up with the 60 on the picture

Comment: You can edit your answer by clicking ont he edit button..it is just below your answer

Comment: Yeah, I changed it already

Answer (score 0):

I put together a javascript code, test it out. Because the line is constrained within a rectangle, we need to handle the case when the line terminates on the right side. In that case, formula $|\frac{4}{\cos \alpha}|$ will not work, it will be $\frac{16}{\sin \alpha}$

`function getLength(angle) {` 
  `var anglerad=angle * Math.PI/180;`
  `if (angle==90) {return 16;}`
  `else`
    `{ a = Math.abs(4/Math.cos(anglerad));`
    `if (a <= 4*Math.sqrt(17)) {return a;}`
    `else {return 16/Math.sin(anglerad);}`
     `}`
`}`

Comment: Thank you for reply @vasili. But this didn't work.

Comment: @narayannyaupane: what case did not work for you? can you give we an example when you did not get the expected result?